# Unable to start DB console service

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, enterprise-manager

I'm using Oracle 11g database in a Windows environment. I've installed Oracle database software only, but now I'm in need of enterprise manager. Initially I tried to start them using the below commands.

```
C:\>set ORACLE_UNQNAME=testdb

C:\>emctl status dbconsole
```

This didn't work as my service for DB console was not up. Then, I tried starting the service which showed up the following error.

[image]

[image]

Can anyone please help me in resolving this error?

Comment: Is the listener working?

Comment: Yes, it's working and also my database is working properly.

Comment: What does it say in the system event log?

Comment: Attaching  the event log message above.

Comment: Have you tried `emctl start dbconsole` and then opening the Entreprise Console?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're running the CMD window "As Administrator".
You will also need to set the ORACLE_SID variable.

```
 set ORACLE_SID=MyOracleSID
 emctl start dbconsole
```

It should provide a more detailed error message at this point, if it does fail.